# Where is the Neutral Bus in this picture of my breaker box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

[image]Hi. I have a rather small breaker box and I'm trying to wire up a new wire with a neutral. I've marked the candidates A, B, C:

Comment: Can you provide photos of the labeling on the inside of the breaker box's door please?

Comment: Yeah, I'd really like to see that label.

Answer (score 2):

If that is your main panel both the neutral and the ground can go to the left. It looks like both A &B are isolated from ground (the metal case) .
But if this is a sub panel the neutral goes on the isolated left buss and the ground goes on the right (they should be isolated)

I believe that  rule came  out in the 99 code change so if your home was built prior to this,  and this is a sub it would have been ok back then for a sub to have both on the same buss, today’s code or since 99 a sub  the neutral is isolated from the ground.